# List Field Name Character Limit

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I'm wanting to give a field a custom name that links it to a row in a separate list. The issue is the fields need to be linked to a string that is a full sentence. One solution would be to have the full sentence as the field name, but this of course wont work if the sentence is longer than the character limit. What is the character limit of a Sharepoint List Field?

Edit:
Sorry, should've been more clear. I was referring to the TITLE of the field not the actual data stored in that column. A comment to one of the answers answered my question, it is 128 characters. Thank you.

Comment: You can search for the boundaries and limits but they are also detailed here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/cc262787(v=office.16).aspx#Column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character limit would be 255 characters for Name / Title. But it is recommended to have Name shorter as the Name is going to be used in queries if required.

Let me know if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: Maximum length for name is actually 128 characters. You should back up your answers with evidence from Technet or MSDN etc. where possible.

Comment: I have created a field with name length 255 characters in SharePoint online site. I don`t know you are referring same.

Answer (score 2):

Document libraries and lists have different options available with respect to the multiple lines of text column type.

In document libraries, when you create a new column of type Multiple Lines of Text, you get the option to select the Allow unlimited length in document libraries checkbox.

But, In lists, this option does not exist.

A multi line text field is defined in SharePoint as a Note type, this is stored in the DB as a ntext sql type. In this SQL type you can store 2gb of char data, that's 1,073,741,823 characters.

Note: It is not advisable to store such huge data in SharePoint column as it may hamper performance.
Explanation referred from this 
    https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/5e8cc504-03d0-4d26-81f9-1608c2c5881f/what-is-the-max-limit-for-number-of-characters-in-multiline-text-in-sharepoint?forum=sharepointgenerallegacy

I hope this is a helpful information!!